# Log4j2 - Is Property Substitution bugged?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

**Log4j2**

Does the `<Properties>` element in the xml configuration file only work if declared as first element under `<Configuration>`?

**Test case 1:**

*TestLog4jBug.java*:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLog4jBug {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
      logger.trace("message");
    }

}
```

*log4j2.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

<Properties>
    <Property name="defaultPatternLayout">[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [Thread: %t] [%level] %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</Property>
</Properties>

<CustomLevels>
    <CustomLevel name="OUTPUT" intLevel="700" />
</CustomLevels>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="console-log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${defaultPatternLayout}" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

*Console output*:

```
[2018-03-29 17:14:49.490] [Thread: main] [TRACE] .main - message
```

**Test case 2:**

*TestLog4jBug.java same as above*

*log4j2.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

<CustomLevels>
    <CustomLevel name="OUTPUT" intLevel="700" />
</CustomLevels>

<Properties>
    <Property name="defaultPatternLayout">[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [Thread: %t] [%level] %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="console-log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${defaultPatternLayout}" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

*Console output*:

```
${defaultPatternLayout}
```

Comment: It looks like `<Properties>` should be the first element in your config https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML

Comment: I've reported this issue to Apache's Jira. Hopefully some log4j developer will clear this up:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2500